# php help, How do I show my "own" order or submission of order

Tags: php

I'm creating code for "transaction logs" for users to check their own order list.

I can probably echo like this

```
<th>Order ID</th> 
<td><?echo $row->orderid?></td>
```

but then again I want to know: how do I call my own order? So specifically I'm using `userID 1`.

Here are the transactions made by `userID/CustomerID 1`

[image: myDatabase]

How would I achieve that?

Comment: Are you just looking for the `WHERE` keyword in SQL?

Comment: uhm not sure if "where"  is the right one im looking for, uhh...   like uh  I want to   echo the order lists made by specifically by Customer ID 1 
http://s8.postimg.org/597f5hrk5/image.png < like how do you do that :o

Comment: Yes, you're looking for the `WHERE` keyword.  As in: `SELECT <fields> FROM <table> WHERE <field> = <value>`

Comment: aight hmmm imma try ><

Comment: which MySQL API are you using to connect with? `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? MSSQL? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from tablename where customerID = 1
```

just change `tablename` with name of your table

Comment: There shouldn't be ticks `\`` around 1, but none at all. If it's a string, then regular quotes `'` should be used. 1 is not a column here.

Comment: True, edited, didn't even see that I made that mistake.

Comment: aight wait immaa tryyyy ><

Comment: uh question,  since it says CustomerID = 1  that means this only works for user 1    how about if its user 2 ,  i mean how to make it work dpending on user logged in / placed an order?  :o

Comment: then you have to combine it with php and calling database, I suggest you check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ for mysql tutorial and http://www.w3schools.com/php/ for php

Comment: You would add customerID to session and when they enter orders you will show orders depending on CustomerID from sessions